# ExtJs RowExpander in Infinite Grid causing incorrect column size

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]

I am using RowExpander [+] plugin in an infinite grid. When I scroll down the buffered page, I see the column width is not correctly lined up as the picture shown. The date column is not trimmed off, it caused the other columns being pushed away. Anyone know why? Thanks.

```
plugins: [{
     ptype: 'bufferedrenderer'
},{
     ptype: 'rowexpander',
     rowBodyTpl: '<div class="inner-results"></div>'
}
```

Comment: Do you have locked column in your grid by setting this: `locked: true` ?

Comment: And my next question what extjs version are you using ?

Comment: I think it has been fixed in some latest 4.2 version but no idea what exactly  build number. For sure this is working in 5.0 and above extjs. Check this: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?272128-column-width-when-using-bufferedrenderer-and-rowexpander

Comment: Yeah. we have 4.2.0 and subscription has expired I think we may not be able to update it.